# how to get KMean clustering prediction with original labels

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I try to use sklearn KMean clustering for supervised learning, where I do have a label for each cluster, somehow while I provide these labels into fitting function `model.fit(X_train, y_train)` , the resulting (output) labels are not from my list but just a cluster number. Can I get the prediction in my original labels?
For example,

training set:

```
x,y,z,class
1,2,3,1001
1,4,8,1002
5,2,9,1003
```

class is y_train for the fit

test set:

```
x,y,z
1,1,1
2,2,2
3,3,3
```

`predicted = model.predict(X_test)` gives me [1 0 2] as the result, while the expected result is [1002 1001 1003]. Docs do not seem to have an option for the labels choice. How to get the prediction with the provided labels ?

Comment: K-means is typically used to cluster unlabeled data. Are you sure you're not looking for something like nearest neighbors?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are looking for a K Nearest Neighbours classifier. This algorithm learns from labeled data, exactly as you describe, and then assigns each point in the test set to one of your pre-defined groups based upon which group has "the most representatives within the nearest neighbors of the point." Here's the implementation:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 3)  # you have 3 groups above
neigh.fit(X_train, y_train)
predicted = neigh.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: KNeighborsClassifier does quite distant stuff, it does not assign a feature vector to one of a predefined class